# Neural Network - My networks seems like is training well, but at classification raport it's completely random

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network, tensor

I'm training a model to classify 3 types of vehicles. Everything seems like going well until I try to predict anything with my model. Results of prediction are completely random.

I'm using 15000 images of 3 classes (5000 each) to train and 6000 images of 3 classes (2000 each) to validate with some Data Augmentation.

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow-GPU backend, making classification report and confusion matrix with use of scikit-learn.
I have no idea why when I'm training the model loss and accuracy both in train and validation are low/high respectively, but confusion matrix is completely random.

## Image Data Generators

```
    img_width, img_height = 96, 96
    train_data_dir = 'data/train'
    validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'

    nb_train_samples = 15000
    nb_validation_samples = 6000

    epochs = 200
    batch_size = 64

 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.3,
        zoom_range=0.3,
        horizontal_flip=True
    )

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./256)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, target_size=(
        img_width, img_height), batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True)
    validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_data_dir, target_size=(
        img_width, img_height), batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True)
```

## Building model

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=image_shape))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(100))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(3))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    adam = optimizers.adam(lr=0.0016643)

    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## Model fitting

```
    es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto')

    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//batch_size, epochs=epochs,
                                validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=nb_validation_samples//batch_size, callbacks=[es], use_multiprocessing=False, workers=6)
```

## Testing my model

```
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(
        validation_generator, steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
    y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
    print('Confusion Matrix')
    cm = confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred)
    print(cm)
    print('Classification Report')
    target_names = ['Car', 'Bus', 'Truck']
    print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes,
                                y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

The output I get looks something like this:

## Output

```
Epoch 1/200
234/234 [==============================] - 35s 149ms/step - loss: 0.9103 - acc: 0.5645 - val_loss: 0.6354 - val_acc: 0.7419
Epoch 2/200
234/234 [==============================] - 30s 130ms/step - loss: 0.6804 - acc: 0.7181 - val_loss: 0.4679 - val_acc: 0.8117
Epoch 3/200
234/234 [==============================] - 30s 129ms/step - loss: 0.6027 - acc: 0.7573 - val_loss: 0.4401 - val_acc: 0.8238
.
.
.
Epoch 37/200
234/234 [==============================] - 30s 128ms/step - loss: 0.2667 - acc: 0.9018 - val_loss: 0.2095 - val_acc: 0.9276
Epoch 38/200
234/234 [==============================] - 30s 129ms/step - loss: 0.2711 - acc: 0.9037 - val_loss: 0.1995 - val_acc: 0.9353

##Here it breaks with an EarlyStopping

Confusion Matrix
[[659 680 661]
 [684 636 680]
 [657 658 685]]
Classification Report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         Car       0.33      0.33      0.33      2000
         Bus       0.32      0.32      0.32      2000
       Truck       0.34      0.34      0.34      2000

   micro avg       0.33      0.33      0.33      6000
   macro avg       0.33      0.33      0.33      6000
weighted avg       0.33      0.33      0.33      6000

dict_keys(['val_loss', 'val_acc', 'loss', 'acc'])
```

Comment: I was going to say overfitting, but it seems like you more or less address it with EarlyStopping. How is the accuracy metric computed?

Comment: @MacieijS did you manage to solve this problem?